# Run a script when connected to wireless (Windows XP)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wireless-networking, command-line

I want my computer to run a script when it connects to my home WLAN.

This [Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/388421/run-a-script-when-connected-to-wireless) is very good but all the options are not available under Windows XP.

Are there Windows XP build in tools to do this?